# How can I update data which is saved with relatiosnships in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I want to update my data with the help of relationship and I already stored this data with the help of relationship. I already stored data in another table.
Creation of data is given below:

```
$data = array('value' => $request->value,);

$followup = FollowupType::create($data);
$parent_id=$request->organization;
$personable = Personne::find($parent_id);
$personable->followup_types()->save($followup);
```

Now I want to know how can I update data?

Comment: Plz give us an example. What do you want to update?

Comment: I've 2 tables which are Personne and Personnable and I'm storing data in both but mendatory to update Personable table. There's no modal of personable table these both tables are connected with each.

Answer (score 0):

If your `personable` and `followup_type` relationship is **many-to-many**, you can use [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) to update, create or delete relationship automatically.

```php
$personable->followup_types()->sync($data);
```

However, if the relationship is **one-to-many**,
unfortunately there is no sync method for one-to-many relations. 
You can do it like this:

```php
$personable->follow_types()->delete();
$personable->followup_types()->saveMany($data);
```

If the relationship is **one-to-one**, just update it.